# Show command output on lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens, lock-screen-widgets

This started out with me wanting a calendar on the lockscreen.  Not a list of events, mind you, but a calendar.  You know, the kind that looks like the periodic table of the elements but with day numbers in the boxes and day-of-week down the columns.  Currently I open up the terminal and type `cal` to get this.

Then I thought "shouldn't I just be able to put `cal` on the lockscreen?"  More generally, I could make a shell script that would print the calendar and maybe some other nice stuff that suits some whim of the moment, and have that show on the lock screen.

Does such an app exist already?  I am using the lockscreen that comes with CyanogenMod 11, if that matters.

Comment: Something like [Month Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.josegd.monthcalwidget)? It doesn't have the other functionality that you'd like (ie. Adding custom stuff) but the core calendar is there.

Comment: @filoxo: thanks, that app looks nice and certainly suits the original problem.  Still interested in answers to the full question though.